# How to determine area of MKMapRect with greatest concentration of MKAnnotation objects?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkmaprect

Given an `MKMapView` that contains a variable amount of annotations (`[mapView annotations]`) at various points on the map and the `MKMapRect` value `MKMapRectWorld`, how can I determine an area on the map that has the greatest concentration on `MKAnnotation` objects (perhaps the 5-15 annotations closest to one another) ?

#### Example scenarios:

* **Coffee finder**: Determine which area of the map has the most Starbucks

* **K9 statistics**: Determine which area of the map has the most Cocker Spaniels

The "area" could be a set rect size or determined by a block of annotations, I don't necessarily care. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "concentration" is tricky word here, given that you don't mention lower limit of number of annotations in any group. for example (theoretically  ) two star bucks might be very close and a small slim rectangle connecting them will have highest concentration. it will be helpful if you limit upper and lower values of star bucks you want.

Comment: @chatur, I've provided an example number range, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200504/how-can-i-reduce-the-number-of-annotations-on-a-map) helpful.

Also take look at     [K-means_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_algorithm)

```
K-means_algorithm
```

If you have N annotations and want to break into K parts you can find center (which will fill certain criteria. e.g. minimize the within-cluster sum of squares ) of each of K parts with  K-means-algorithm. Once you have center find out distance between center and annotation farthest from center it will give  radius of region you are interested. There are several variations of K-means_algorithm, you can choose whichever based on performance and ease of implementation.

EDIT:
I have not implemented following, but think will definitely give one of solution

If you are OK with range 5-10, there can be multiple solutions. So we will find one of solution.

1- Say you have (N=100) annotations and want which (P =15)  of them are most located densely.

2- Then we will divide N annotations in K = N/P groups(here K = 7) randomly

3- Use K-means algorithm so that finally we will have K groups that can be differentiated as  separate entities.

4- These K groups will have property of minimum " within-cluster sum of squares".

5- If you want to save computational time, you can relax definition of most concentrated group as minimum "within-cluster sum of squares" as opposed to area bounded by them.

6- select a group from obtained K group that satisfies your criteria.

7- If want to persist to minimum area(greatest concentration) definition then you will need to do lots of computation

a. First determine boundary annotations of given group, which itself a huge problem.

b. calculate are of each polygon and see which is least. not complicated but computationally demanding)

`EDIT2`:

I tried whatever I can and finally thought it this question belongs to specialist math website. I asked your question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86793/find-most-densely-located-k-points-among-n-nk-points-in-two-dimension) and from the answer , you can get paper discussing this problem and solution  [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%09new%20algorithms%20for%20minimum%20area%20k-gons&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-TR-91-59.pdf&ei=opciT-KZD4nzrQfGk7HCCA&usg=AFQjCNG31ZcX0Mv0w250nTM2_A7EXGN-5Q&sig2=2YVlui9lZbW2gwvMnO36Pg&cad=rja). Problem they discuss is given N points, find the K points whose area of [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) is minimum.

Comment: Isn't K-means more for several clusters when I want only one that represents the single area of greatest concentration?

Comment: The resources you provided under EDIT2 look promising. Thanks for the help.