# How to load only few annotations around current location?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, dictionary, annotations

I read through many topic but i don't think i really get them.

I found the following code in one of the topic but I am not sure how to put it. Should i put in viewdidload? or somewhere else?

And I have a large annotation data of 3000 dots. But I dont know how to read a sqlite data (I am using a plist data) Please give me a help.

Thanks in advance.

```
// create and populate an array containing all potential annotations
NSMutableArray *allPotentialAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array];

for(all potential annotations)
{
    MyAnnotation *myannotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc]
                              initWithCoordinate:...whatever...];
    [allPotentialAnnotations addObject:myannotation];
    [myannotation release];
}

// set the user's current location as the reference location
[allPotentialAnnotations
 makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setReferenceLocation:) 
 withObject:mapView.userLocation.location];

// sort the array based on distance from the reference location, by
// utilising the getter for 'distanceFromReferenceLocation' defined
// on each annotation (note that the factory method on NSSortDescriptor
// was introduced in iOS 4.0; use an explicit alloc, init, autorelease
// if you're aiming earlier)
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = 
[NSSortDescriptor
 sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distanceFromReferenceLocation" 
 ascending:YES];

[allPotentialAnnotations sortUsingDescriptors:
 [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

// remove extra annotations if there are more than five
if([allPotentialAnnotations count] > 5)
{
    [allPotentialAnnotations
     removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(5, 
                                      [allPotentialAnnotations count] - 5)];
}

// and, finally, pass on to the MKMapView
[mapView addAnnotations:allPotentialAnnotations];
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the first thing to do is clustering your data on the map. that means combining several points to one point on the map. the more the user zoomes in the more the clusters will be resolved to single points placed on the map.

there are some recommendations how to do that in this post:

[How can I reduce the number of annotations on a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200504/how-can-i-reduce-the-number-of-annotations-on-a-map)

the next step is to itterate through your data and check if one point is within the region arround the user location. you can get the GEO position of the visible display area like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2d topLeft, bottomRight;
topLeft = [mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
CGPoint pointBottomRight = CGPointMake(mapView.frame.size.width, mapView.frame.size.height);
bottomRight = [mapView convertPoint:pointBottomRight toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
```