# Avoiding MapView Pin-Clumping?

Tags: mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I am adding pins to a MKMapView using MKPinAnnotation view and was wondering if there is a way to stop pin-clumping (i.e. all the pins showing when zoomed out). Is there a way to do this using the API or  do I have to manually filter the annotations to be added based on the current zoom amount?

[image]

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200504/how-can-i-reduce-the-number-of-annotations-on-a-map useful

Answer (score 3):

`MapKit` does not provide a way to cluster the annotation views itself. You basically have two options. You can manually remove/hide the annotations yourself or use a third party framework like [OCMapView](https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView). I have not used it myself so I can't comment on how good it is.

Comment: Thank you Ross, I will probably look at doing this myself as that way I can better control the amalgam of pin data at each zoom level. Thanks again for your quick reply, its much appreciated.